# How to log request data along with response data in http:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Using spring integration, I am reading from a queue and then calling a REST service using http:outbound-gateway. The code works fine. But I want to relate the logs such that for a given request key field , so and so response is received. Otherwise, it is very difficult to pinpoint for which request the response is received, when there are thousands of messages flowing through the queue.

My JSON request for the service call is as follows:
{"ID":"123","status":"A"}

my JSON Response from the service call is as follows:
{"transactionStatus":"Success"}

I want to do logging such that **"ID:123" has got a reponse transactionStatus as "Success".**
Please help me with the code how I can achieve this. Please let me know if you need further details.
Thanks in advance.

```
<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel = "gcmRequestChannel" output-channel="RESTSrvcChannel"></int:object-to-json-transformer>

<int:header-enricher id = "restenricher" input-channel = "RESTSrvcChannel" output-channel = "RESTSrvcChannel2">
    <int:header name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
    <int:header name="SPApikey" value="${throttler.SPApikey}" />
</int:header-enricher>
 <http:outbound-gateway id="gcmrestHttpOutboundGateway" request-channel="RESTSrvcChannel2" reply-channel="nullChannel"
                       extract-request-payload="true"
                       url="${throttler.url}"
                       header-mapper="headerMapper"
                       http-method="POST"
                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                       >

</http:outbound-gateway>
<beans:bean id="headerMapper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <beans:property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,SPApikey" />
    <beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring Integration deals with the `Message` object in its components and via channels in between, there is a nice solution like supply your important information into the headers and they will be available in the `replyMessage` for your logging purpose:

```
<header-enricher>
    <header name="originalPayload" expression="payload"/>
</header-enricher>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have coded as suggested by you. Thanks for your response.

```
<int:header-enricher id = "gcmrestenricher" input-channel = "gcmRESTSrvcChannel" output-channel = "gcmRESTSrvcChannel2">
    <int:header name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
    <int:header name="SPApikey" value="${throttler.SPApikey}" />
    <int:header name="JSONPayload" expression="payload"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<http:outbound-gateway id="gcmrestHttpOutboundGateway" request-channel="gcmRESTSrvcChannel2" reply-channel="gcmRESTSrvcOutputChannel"
                       extract-request-payload="true"
                       url="${throttler.gcmurl}"
                       header-mapper="gcmheaderMapper"
                       http-method="POST"
                       expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                       >

</http:outbound-gateway>
<beans:bean id="gcmheaderMapper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <beans:property name="inboundHeaderNames" value="*" />
    <beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,SPApikey,JSONPayload" />
    <beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="logmsg" class = "com.MLAServiceActivator"></beans:bean>
<int:service-activator requires-reply="false" input-channel="gcmRESTSrvcOutputChannel" ref="logmsg" method="ResponseLogging"></int:service-activator>


@ServiceActivator
public void ResponseLogging(Message<String> message)
{
    logger.info("The response message is:"+message.getPayload()+ " for request message:"+message.getHeaders().get("JSONPayload"));
}
```